# Generic in Java

Tags: java, generics

i have a test with generic in java. This is my code:
Code 1:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Convert<String, Integer> c = new Convert<>();
//        Integer number = c.convert("a");
        System.out.println(c.convert("a"));
    }

    static class Convert<E, T> {
        public T convert(E element) {
            return (T) element;
        }
    }
}
```

and Code 2:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Convert<String, Integer> c = new Convert<>();
        Integer number = c.convert("a");
        System.out.println(number);
    }

    static class Convert<E, T> {
        public T convert(E element) {
            return (T) element;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run code 1, output is "a", but when I run code 2, it appear Exception.
Why code 1 still print "a"?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: These are really three questions: 1) why does Code 2 not work is easily answered, but then there is 2) why does Code 1 work, and 3) HOW does Code 1 work. I have no ideas on 2) and 3).

Comment: Exception such as what?

Answer (score 6):

In Java, the behavior of generics is closely tied to type erasure. Both of your Convert class versions are utilizing unchecked casts, which is not a good practice and can lead to issues like you're facing.

```
System.out.println(c.convert("a"));
```

In this case, you are not assigning the output of c.convert("a") to an Integer variable. The method System.out.println(Object obj) will print the string representation of any object, so this code works without a problem. The result of c.convert("a") is actually an Object, and System.out.println has no issue with that.

```
Integer number = c.convert("a");
```

In this case, you're trying to force an assignment from Object (what convert method actually returns due to type erasure) to Integer. At runtime, Java attempts to cast the String "a" to Integer, which is not a valid operation, so a ClassCastException is thrown.

For the reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: It's not just about assigning to an `Integer` variable: if you invoke a method on the result - even a method found on `Object` - you'll get a `ClassCastException`: `c.convert("a").toString()` https://ideone.com/5Tsi0e

Comment: @AndyTurner Interesting. So in your example Java tries to call `Integer#toString()`, which is logical, and which obviously gives that exception. I bet `((Object) c.convert("a")) .toString()` would work.

Comment: @Ole actually the compiler is adding a `checkcast`, like if we had `Integer number = (Integer) c.convert("a");` (it is then calling `println(Object)`, that means, still calling `Object#toString`

Comment: @AndyTurner so what does a cast to type (T) really do after type erasure and there is no T left at all? Cast to Object? Deffer the decision until the object is used, and than throw an error no matter what?

Comment: @GyroGearloose `(T)` is an unchecked cast: there is no bytecode instruction inserted for it, so nothing happens there at runtime. The cast is inserted at the call site; and no, it doesn't throw "no matter what": OP has presented code where it doesn't throw; also, it doesn't throw if the call site cast succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Your "convert" doesn't change the structure of the data, just the pretended type.

So you cast your data from class String to class Integer, just *declaring* it would be an Integer.

Without changing the structure.

You can parse the String to make it an Integer, but just calling a *cat* to be a *dog* won't do the trick.

---

Edit: you can cast primitive types, but not Object s, not unless the objects are in the same hierarchy.

How should the compiler know how you would like to be two unrelated Objects to be converted?

Answer (score -1):

in code1:
because Erasure in Runtime RawType generic.
in Code2:
because Erasure in Runtime RawType generic cause uchecking cast
and Integer can't cast to String

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).