# Use of generic cast operation in Java

Tags: generics, casting, type-parameter, jls

Consider the following code snippet:

```java
public static <T> T convertInstanceOfObject(Object o) {
    try {
        T rv = (T)o;
        return rv;
    } catch(java.lang.ClassCastException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

- now here the line `T rv = (T)o;` shows that we are converting the object of type Object to a type T.
- My doubt is that why the syntax needs a redundant `(T)` to be specified when it ultimately gets converted to the `Object` type at the runtime?
- I mean - had the statement formation been `T rv = o;` the compiler would have understood the same thing.
  And the statement `T rv = (T)o;` is not doing any good afterall when `(T)` is being used as the casting operator.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77346996/4142984 . A cast in java does not change the nature of an Object, it just calls it by another name. Calling your cat a dog doesn't make it bark.